# Redis::TimeoutError from Ruby to Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, redis

I am trying to access the Azure Redis Cache service from Ruby on Rails. I have the gem 'redis' (3.1.0) installed. I want to accomplish this using SSL.

This is my code in `config/initializers/redis.rb`

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => '[APP_NAME].redis.cache.windows.net', :port => 6380, :db => 10)
$redis.auth("[ACCESS_TOKEN]")
```

I then run `rails c` and get the "Connection timed out" 100% of the time on the auth call. I have this working in .NET, so I'm not sure why it is failing here.

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:55:in `rescue in _read_from_socket': Connection timed out (Redis::TimeoutError)
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:48:in `_read_from_socket'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:41:in `gets'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:273:in `read'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:238:in `block in read'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:226:in `io'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:237:in `read'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102:in `block in call'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in process'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:329:in `ensure_connected'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:197:in `block in process'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `logging'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:196:in `process'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102:in `call'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:87:in `block in connect'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:266:in `with_reconnect'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `connect'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:326:in `ensure_connected'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:197:in `block in process'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `logging'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:196:in `process'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102:in `call'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:64:in `block in auth'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
   from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:63:in `auth'
   from /vagrant/dragondoor/config/initializers/redis.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: I've also tried this with https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-rb, but still no luck.

Comment: Try connecting to the non-SSL port (6379) instead.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I want to use SSL.

Comment: Ok, it's just that it wasn't apparent from the question so you may want to add that to it :)

Comment: Add for using Azure's SSL with our fork of redis-rb, I believe that won't work because we require a certificate, whereas Azure's is Bauer based on key or something IIRC.

Comment: Updated the OP. Thanks for your help. I have a ticket with Microsoft to see how I can connect. Will update here with results.

Comment: How do you know the db number is 10?

Comment: The db number doesn't matter. It's whatever your application uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'redis', github: 'RedisLabs/redis-rb', branch: 'ssl'
```

In `config/initializers/redis.rb`

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => '[APP_NAME].redis.cache.windows.net', :port => 6380, :db => 10, :password => "[ACCESS_TOKEN]", :use_ssl => true)
```